# Relación entre tablas muchos a muchos

Tags: mysql

Tengo dos tablas en el cual tengo 1 campo en común el cual necesito que esté relacionado. Os pongo en situación.

Tengo un identificador_grupo el cual es numérico ese identificador se repite constantemente, por ejemplo

```
Nombre | Apellidos | identificador de grupo

Manolo | Perez     | 2
Pepito | Perez     | 6
Gustavo| Perez     | 3
Maria  | Perez     | 2
Lorena | Perez     | 3
```

Luego tengo una tabla que se llama sesiones

```
Fecha      | Hora  | grupo_id

12/03/2019 | 08:30 | 2
20/07/2019 | 10:15 | 6
18/04/2019 | 11:25 | 3
21/06/2019 | 12:05 | 3
30/01/2019 | 14:22 | 2
```

Entonces necesito que grupo_id esté relacionado con identificador_grupo, no se si me expliqué bien Y.Y

Uso MySQL y PHPMyAdmin

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Y cual es el problema?

Comment: Que no se como puedo hacerlo, ya que al ser de muchos a muchos no puedo relacionarlas entre sí, o almenos no me deja

Comment: Si, pero ¿que es lo que quieres conseguir? ¿un select?

Comment: Sacar los datos por pantalla, que estén relacionados

Comment: si es una relación de muchos a muchos, no hace falta una tercera tabla?

Comment: Lo suyo es hacer un `SELECT * FROM A JOIN sesiones s ON s.grupo_id=A.identificador_de_grupo` pero me temo que lo que quieres es relacionar las personas con su fecha de sesion. Si es así olvidate es imposible pues no tienes esa relación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día, lo que necesitas es hacer un inner join, puedes hacerlo así, como no especificaste como se llaman las tablas tendrás que sustituir los nombres por los correctos.

```
Select tab1.*, tab2.* from NombreTabla1 tab1 INNER JOIN NombreTablaSesiones tab2 ON tab1.identificador_grupo = tab2.grupo_id
```

Con eso obtendrías la relación.

Saludos